# Is there a way to send a response to an opened session without a request?

Tags: java, tomcat, httpresponse

I want to send data (what I call a response) to a previous Http requester (assuming a newer request came to the same servlet) through the already old formed session (which is still alive).

The reason is that an occurring event (which is NOT another request in the same session in question) wants the servlet to say something (a string) through our old session to our old requester (assuming another requester came).
Is there an way (a hint) to do that?

(( Edit :
I know it's not usual for HTTP communication. And I'm afraid that if the socket (of layer 5 of OSI) closes after the "service" method ends then my question doesn't hold in the first place and probably I would have to stop socket from closing by going into an API of the server container ("Tomcat" in my case). 
This is probably the case by looking onto [this](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/javax/websocket/Session.java).
))

Anyway, here is what I've tried to do :

1) I tried to save the HttpServletResponse object (in the "service" method) of the session in question, but then when a newer request (from another requester) came (and by consequence the "service" method in the same servlet, name it "servlet1", will be executed again), it appeared to me, oddly enough to me, clearly that the HttpServletResponse that I saved is overritten.

2) I found the same result (I was even more surprised) when I tried to save the PrintWriter object (in the following shown code) I got from HttpServletResponse.getWriter(). And again, it was overritten when another request came.

3) I had a hope with HttpSession but I doubt I'm able to write through it. (check its methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html))

Again, I just want to write a string and get it there in (my) client side. If there is a sort of control I can take on the session to send a string, and a way to get it on the client, that would be good.

```
class Session {
    protected PrintWriter printWriter;
    protected int index;
    Session(PrintWriter pW, int index) {
        this.printWriter = pW;
        this.index = index;
    }
}
@WebServlet("/servlet1")
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
private static int session_index = 0;
    protected static volatile ArrayList<Session> list = new ArrayList<Session>();

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        session_index++;
        System.out.println( "Servlet1 : " + session_index );
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        list.add(new Session(response.getWriter(), session_index));
        if( list.get(0).printWriter.equals( response.getWriter() ) ) {
            System.out.println( "Servlet1 : same old PrintWriter object" );
        }
    }
```

I expected this message "Servlet1 : same old PrintWriter object" to not appear in my console, but it did in all subsequent requests.

It is Tomcat 9.0.21 installed on Linux, that I'm working with on the server side (localhost).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I will need to modify the server container itself, so I will download the source code from [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi) and will follow [this guideline](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/BUILDING.txt) to build the Tomcat. The modification must be made in such a way not to close the socket. I may add a method in the servlet to close the socket manually.